# Bash script does not give the same result when running it in a script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tty

I'm trying to learn Bash scripting. when i use the command directly in the bash

```
find . -xdev -type d -path ./sys -o -path ./proc -o -path ./run -prune -o -iname "*.txt"
```

This gives me a buch of results while

But when I use the same code in a script file

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

find . -xdev -type d -path ./sys -o -path ./proc -o -path ./run -prune -o -iname "$1"
~
```

Gives me only one result.

PS: Don't take the extglob seriosly I was trying to do it with parentheses.

Tried to add shopt -s extglob, tried different variants of code. Command with parentheses didn't work even when I added `shopt -s extglob`

Created a file named "bul" and put the code inside, chmoded it with +x and put the file in ~/.local/bin where i want to run directly from my terminal(I have the path in my .bashrc)

I removed shopt -s extglob from the code,

I have text.txt file in my home folder and 2 .txt files in my ~/Documents/ folder. It's only finds the file in the home folder. where i search from. Even when i it must start searching from / root.

EDIT: When i search directly from terminal with command:

```
find . -xdev -type d '(' -path './sys/*' -o -path './proc/*' -o -path './run/*' ')' -prune -o -name *.txt -print
```

It's gives me the correct result.

But when i run it wild wildcard with command `bul . *.txt` it's give me the result:

```
+ find . -xdev -type d '(' -path './sys/*' -o -path './proc/*' -o -path './run/*' ')' -prune -o -name text.txt -print
```

It's searching "text.txt"

SOLVED: When i type the command in terminal like "bul . *.txt" it doesn't work but when i qouted second argument 'bul . "*.txt"' like this it works.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: `use the same code` but it has `"$1"`

Comment: please update the question with the *`one result`* generated by the script as well as a sample of what's generated when run at the command prompt; also, confirm whether or not you issued `shopt -s extglob` prior to running the command at the command prompt; also, please show how you're calling the script (of particular interest is the parameter(s) supplied to the script

Comment: How are you running the script? If you want to pass a filename wildcard as `$1`, you have to quote it. `./scriptname '*.txt'`

Comment: Otherwise the shell expands the wildcard, and `$1` just contains the first matching name.

Comment: When debugging a script, one of the first steps is to put `set -x` at the beginning. Then you'll see the expansion of the variables, which should clue you into the problem.

Comment: Put a `echo $1` at the beginning of your script to see what is actually in `$1`

Comment: Why are you expecting the **bash** extglob option to control how **find** does wildcard matching?

Comment: Confirm you using the same directory as the `.` value in your find command. You could replace the `.` with a hard-coded path in both usages, i.e. `find /path/to/start/search ....` . Good luck.

Comment: You were given a correct explanation of the problem in Barmar's comment 22 hours ago now. Why is this question still being edited?

Comment: @LjmDullaart, no, `echo $1` is actively misleading. It would need to be `echo "$1"` -- see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else).